# Install Laravel Compiling Assets (Mix) with composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mix

Is there any possibility to install and run Laravel Compiling Assets ([Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix)) with use only composer?

Comment: Mix is an independent javascript plugin. You can download that independently and use it. Documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Composer is for PHP packages

Laravel Mix is to compile JavaScript. You install it with npm.

Answer (score 1):

[Mix](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix) is based on [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) which requires [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) to compile assets (both js and css).

So you need to install node on your server and then run (depending on your setup):

```
npm run build
```